# DNode implementation for websocket communication in node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, dnode, sockjs

I don't understand the way **DNode** uses **websocket** communication.
Some say it uses **socket.io** others say **sockjs**.
Which one is it? Or is it possible to choose?

I'm trying to use DNode, but I also need access to the **connections** for (semi-)broadcasting in reaction to RPC calls. How do I do this?

Is there a more extensive manual on dnode somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of vague. I'm not exactly sure whether DNode uses socket.io or sockjs, not sure it even uses one of those based on their dependencies list, but that is not really important when you program it.

As for using connections with DNode, it is pretty straight forward. Here's an example:

```
var server = dnode({
    pushMessageNotification: function(message, cb) {
        contact = getClientFromId(message.receiver);
        contact.socket.emit('messageNotification', {
            message: message.message,
            sender: message.sender,
            time: message.time
        });
        cb('success');
    }
});
```

So as you can see, pushMessageNotification is a method that I binded with DNode-PHP and the message is encoded in JSON through PHP. Afterward, all you need is a method to find the socket of the client based on its id.